# Which is a normal temperature for a laptop?

Tags: laptop, nvidia-optimus, temperature

I have a Samsung series 5 my temperature is around 77-80°c when i am playing, and 48-54 on normal use it laptop don't have a month and I am not sure if it is normal.

```
Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4    
8 GB of RAM    
Nvidia optimus 650M (I am using Bumblebee)    
Ubuntu 12.04
```

Comment: I think thats about normal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Intel site, [Link to your CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/67355/Intel-Core-i5-3210M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz-rPGA), after Tjunction you have 105ºC. This means that it stands up to that temperature.

Normal may be a matter of opinion, but for me, normal is between 50ºC to 70ºC for low usage and up to 80ºC if all the processors are working close to 100%. If somehow the 90ºC are passed I would say that something is wrong.

Comment: If it was usefull, help me by voting it up ;)

Comment: i can´t requires 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

Those temperatures look fine to me for that kind of configuration.  I've seen far worse.

Answer (score 0):

my computer runs at 80C at 40% and 95C at 70% and 105+C at 100%, and with a cooling pad runs about 20C cooler for them all. i think that is normal for a laptop with a crappy cooler xD