# Noisy fan on Ubuntu 14 04 ATI Radeon 7000 series

Tags: 14.04, drivers, fglrx, amd-graphics, overheating

I have Ubuntu 14 04 with ATI Radeon 7000. The fan is making much noise and the laptop is heating. A similar question has been asked [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473414/ubuntu-14-04-and-amd-radeon-hd-7670m-overheat-problem) and its solution is not working for me. I am getting a bug when following the installation. The same bug is being returned by many users. **The bug is documented [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1676079).**

Can I get some help about the different possibilities I have to solve this problem ?

Comment: Clean the fan and everything else. And set proper expectations for ancient hardware. The "bug" is not what you think it is ("undecided" and "unassigned" should be enough as clues). The old proprietary drivers do not work with newer kernels/X server and the new drivers do not support legacy hardware. It's that simple. You do *not* have any other possibility, the open-source driver should work fine with your hardware and the symptom is of old unmantained hardware, nothing to do with software.

Comment: which open source driver are you referring to ?

Comment: `radeon`, installed and used by default.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, can you provide a link to the driver you are referring to ?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the possibility that there is a hardware issue with the noisy fan and therefore the problem is not a bug or reproducible as a software issue.

If a computer fan is making an annoying noise, it is often also the case that the computer is running hotter than it needs to run due to a mechanical problem with a worn out fan. Replacing the fan not only eliminates the noise, but may also lower your computer's temperatures because the replacement fan may also run faster in addition to running more quietly.<sup>**[1](https://superuser.com/questions/890422/annoying-fan-noise-vs-slow-down/890430#890430)**</sup>

Comment: Alternatively the fan or the general inside of the computer case is clogged with dust and the fan needs to spin faster and emit more noise to keep the temperature at an acceptable level if at all possible.

Comment: If the cooling block adjacent to a computer fan needs to be cleaned, the fan will work harder and make a little more noise, but a noisy fan that makes a loud rattling noise is typically caused by a mechanical issue with the fan.

Comment: I agree. However, the question doesn't say anything about the tone or volume of the noise.

Comment: The question says "much noise" which I interpreted as being a loud fan that has a mechanical issue.

Comment: You're probably right but these things are often subjective and I wanted to offer a variation of your solution for another plausible interpretation of the question. Personally, I have a CPU fan that gets annoyingly loud if I make spin it at full speed and that's definitely not a failing bearing. :-)