# What troubleshooting steps should I take if my machine seems to be overheating and slowing down?

Tags: overheating

There are a lot (a lot) of related questions, but as far as I can tell they're all fairly low quality or hyper specific. There are also a lot of articles online about managing overheating but it's hard to tell if any are particularly reputable.

Right now my machine, a laptop running 20.04, seems to be freezing up fairly often and running hot to the touch.

The fan runs fairly loudly when it slows down. I am already cautious about keeping a book or board under it so that the vents aren't blocked even when it's actually on my lap (so it doesn't get buried in folds of blankets or anything).

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Seeing your [very recent answer on a similar post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335369/1157519) I have the impression that you are fabricating a would-be canonical question. Which might not be a bad thing on its own right (I don't know), but the spirit of [this meta question](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19579/1157519) (and answer) appears to discourage this.

Comment: Making sure bios is updated helps sometimes.  You have probably read about making sure laptop is clean inside.  Most other solutions would deal with specific make and model of machine.  Do you have psensors or similar on machine to check temps?

Comment: @Levente I'm actually not. That post was very specific but the next steps were pretty obvious and mentioned in the comments. My answer there is pretty incomplete, as answers go. And reading that post did not get me closer to any solutions for my own machine so I still have troubleshooting to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 14 04 ATI Radeon 7000 Series](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907854/ubuntu-14-04-ati-radeon-7000-series)