# My fan is too loud

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, fan

first sorry for my bad English.

I have old Sony Vaio VGN-FW11M with Intel Pentium T4300 Dual Core 2.10Ghz and Ati Mobility Radeon HD4300 graphic card.

My fan is too loud, everything works perfect but fan is always too loud and on same speed.. It is crazy and I can't work with that loud fans.

CPU usage is normal, with chrome and some apps is arround 50% usage, not higher.

On windows fan normal works, its loud when CPU usage is 90-100%..

Is problem in graphic card? I can't find graphic card driver..

I use Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Noisy fan on Ubuntu 14 04 ATI Radeon 7000 series](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907854/noisy-fan-on-ubuntu-14-04-ati-radeon-7000-series)  and [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/q/815591/)

Comment: Maybe you should replace fan and thermal paste ?